# "Консультироваться у врача" или "консультироваться с врачом"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "консультироваться у врача" или "консультироваться с врачом"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Консультироваться — с кем и у кого. Я понял, что мой доклад будет иметь строгих критиков, но не смутился, потому что накануне *консультировался с* Соколовым (И. Чернышов). *Консультировались* мы *у* академиков, и у различных специалистов, и у домохозяек (Ушаков).

Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д. Э. Розенталь.

Answer (score 1):

Не ручаюсь за то, что скажу непреложную истину, но мне кажется, что ***консультироваться у врача*** значит приходить к нему за советом как ***пациент***, а ***консультироваться с врачом*** может как ***пациент***, так и ***другой врач***, обсуждая с ним на равных какой-то медицинский вопрос.